# Typing a generic groupby function in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to do the typings for a groupBy function that takes an optional transformer function that can be used to modify the data after it has been grouped. I'm not getting the typescript compiler to understand what it is I want and was wondering what I should try next?

```
export const groupByList = <A extends {}, C, B extends keyof any>(
  extractKey: (o: A) => B,
  data: A[],
  transformer?: (o: A) => C
) =>
  data.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => ({
      ...acc,
      [extractKey(cur)]: (acc[extractKey(cur)] ?? []).concat(
        transformer ? transformer(cur) : cur
      ),
    }),
    {} as Record<B, (A | C)[]>
  )

// Usage

const myList = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }]

const res1 = groupByList(
  (x) => x.a,
  myList,
)

//Actual  type of res1: Record<number, unknown[]>
//Desired  type of res1:  Record<number, {a: number}[]>

const res2 = groupByList( 
  (x) => x.a,
  myList,
  (x) => ({ b: x.a })
)

//Actual  type of res2: Record<number, ({ a: number; } | { b: number; })[]>
//Desired  type of res2:  Record<number, {b: number}[]>
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for @jcalz. But my gut feeling says you might need the `infer` keyword https://learntypescript.dev/09/l2-conditional-infer

Comment: Let jcalz rest a bit, you can do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY33xN).

Comment: Why is it safe to use any though?

Comment: @revilotom `any` is OK here because it won't "leak" and spread into whatever code is using the function. `keyof any` is also just `string | number | symbol`.

Comment: @caTS This may be a stupid question but is there an easy way to tell whether an any will "leak" or if it will be contained?

Comment: Yeah, just use it and then if it does, undo it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use function overloading to achieve the desired result.

```
// Overloading with not transformer
export function groupByList<A extends {}, B extends PropertyKey>(
  extractKey: (o: A) => B,
  data: A[],
): Record<B, A[]>;

// Overloading with transformer
export function groupByList<A extends {}, B extends PropertyKey, C>(
  extractKey: (o: A) => B,
  data: A[],
  transformer: (o: A) => C,
): Record<B, C[]>;

// Actual implementation
export function groupByList<A extends {}, B extends PropertyKey, C>(
  extractKey: (o: A) => B,
  data: A[],
  transformer?: (o: A) => C,
) {
  // Added type for reduce to get rid of index issues. 
  // Added partial to avoid error with the reduce initial value
  return data.reduce<Partial<Record<B, (A | C)[]>>>(
    (acc, cur) => ({
      ...acc,
      [extractKey(cur)]: (acc[extractKey(cur)] ?? []).concat(transformer?.(cur) ?? cur),
    }),
    {},
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't need an overload if you make the parameter optional and have C default to the identity function `(_: T) => T` like my playground link (from 6 months ago, mind you) shows.